# Variable scope with in different ruby file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir

i am autpmating a web site that have different function page.
i am making differnt modules for each function.
the problem is that i have a login page Login.rb
that has the below code :-

```
$IE = Watir::IE.new_process

module Login

  def Login.login(url)
    $IE.goto("url")
    sleep (4)
    $IE.maximize
    #$IE.span(:class =>'menuLink', :text =>'Image').click
  end
end
```

i need to access $IE variable to my other modules methods.
the problem is that the other modules that are in different .rb file are not taking this variable.
help me how sholud i declare this so that i can use it in all my modules throughout different files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables should be available in all modules and in all files.  You could put this global variable in a file named (for example) common.rb and require or load that file in all of your scripts.

But you don't need to use a global variable.  You could just as easily do something like this and load it in every script file that you need.

```
module Browser
  def self.ie
    @ie ||= Watir::IE.new_process
  end
end
```